# What is the optimal way to match list entries after rounding in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have two lists in Mathematica:

```
list1 = {{a1, b1, c1}, ... , {an, bn, cn}}
```

and

```
list2 = {{d1, e1, f1}, ... , {dn, en, fn}}
```

the lists contain numerical results and are roughly consisting of 50000 triplets each. Each triplet represents two coordinates and a numerical value of some property at these coordinates. Each list has different length and the coordinates are not quite the same range. My intention is to correlate the numerical values of the third property from each list so I need to scan through the lists and identify the properties whose coordinates are matching. My output will be something like

```
list3 = {{ci, fj}, ... , {cl, fm}}
```

where

```
{ai, bi}, ..., {al, bl}
```

will be (roughly) equal to, respectively

```
{dj, ej}, ..., {dm, em}
```

By "roughly" I mean the coordinates will match once rounded to some desired accuracy:

```
list1(2) = Round[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}, {1000, 500, 0.1}] & /@ list1(2)
```

so after this process I's have two lists that contain some matching coordinates amongst them. My question is how to perform the operation of identifying them and picking out the pairs of properties in the optimal way?

An example of a 6 element list would be

```
list1 = {{-1.16371*10^6, 548315., 14903.}, {-1.16371*10^6, 548322., 14903.9}, 
   {-1.16371*10^6, 548330., 14904.2}, {-1.16371*10^6, 548337., 14904.8}, 
   {-1.16371*10^6, 548345., 14905.5}, {-1.16371*10^6, 548352., 14911.5}}
```

Comment: can you post small numerical examples for `list1` and `list2` and the expected output `list3`? Also, define "roughly".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to use something like this:

```
{Round[{#, #2}], #3} & @@@ Join[list1, list2];

% ~GatherBy~ First ~Select~ (Length@# > 1 &)
```

This will group all data points that having matching coordinates after rounding.  You can use a second argument to `Round` to specify the fraction to round by.

This assumes that there are not duplicated points within a single list.  If there are, you will need to remove those to get useful pairs.  Tell me if this is the case and I will update my answer.

Here is another method using `Sow` and `Reap`.  The same caveats apply.  Both of these examples are simply guidelines for how you may implement your functionality.

```
Reap[
  Sow[#3, {Round[{#, #2}]}] & @@@ Join[list1, list2],
  _,
  List
][[2]] ~Cases~ {_, {_, __}}
```

---

To deal with duplicate-after-round elements within each list, you may use `Round` and `GatherBy` on each list as follows.

```
newList1 = GatherBy[{Round[{#, #2}], #3} & @@@ list1, First][[All, 1]];

newList2 = GatherBy[{Round[{#, #2}], #3} & @@@ list2, First][[All, 1]];
```

and then proceed with:

```
newList1 ~Join~ newList2 ~GatherBy~ First ~Select~ (Length@# > 1 &)
```

Comment: Mr.Wizard - yes, this looks promising but as you said, after rounding there may be elements in each list with duplicate coordinates in which case a single representative element would suffice.

Comment: +1, for the most ingenious (insidious?) use of infix form I've seen.

Comment: @gpap if that is the case we will need to filter each list first.  I will amend my answer.

Comment: @rcollyer I hope it is not hard to read.  I decided recently to start posting code with infix notation as I would write it for my own use.

Comment: I can't find the `~` in my (mental) keyboard :)

Comment: It's a tad confusing at first sight, especially as it doesn't emphasize the grouping (`(#1 ~GatherBy~ #2) ~Select~ #3`) :D  I usually use infix for associative functions only such as `Join` (which implies that all arguments are of the same type).

Comment: It took a moment to mentally parse how it would work, and realizing that `%~GatherBy~First` in its entirety was treated as input to `Select`. Or, more precisely, its result was the input. I'd argue that you should continue to use it in posts as it is a little challenging, and people can exposed to more "exotic" forms.

Comment: @Szabolcs, the binding is simply left to right, therefore I find this line to read naturally: `newList1 ~Join~ newList2 ~GatherBy~ First ~Select~ (Length@# > 1 &)`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was about to Round then use Intersection with a clever SameTest to filter out the similar entries but I doubt it would be quicker than yours. Works a treat, thanks a lot!

Comment: @gpap You're welcome.  I doubt you will find a faster method than `GatherBy` as it is very efficient.  However, do not be too quick to Accept (the green checkmark) an answer, as it may discourage others from posting good answers too.  Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yup, GatherBy is definitely faster (confirmed now). I've also un-accepted the answer as per the true newbie's code of conduct so will give it a little more time before I tick. In any case, that's a really cool way of doing this - I had only used ~ in manipulating strings so your answer's an eye-opener.

Comment: @gpap I like that ~infix~ makes it clear that there are exactly two arguments.  I also find that often, as the last line of code above, it reads almost literally.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my approach, relying on [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Nearest.html) to match the points.

Let's assume that `list1` doesn't have fewer elements than `list2`.  (Otherwise you can swap them using `{list1, list2} = {list2, list1}`)

```
(* extract points *)

points1=list1[[All,{1,2}]];
points2=list2[[All,{1,2}]];

(* build a "nearest-function" for matching them *)

nf=Nearest[points1]

(* two points match only if they're closer than threshold *)
threshold=100;

(* This function will find the match of a point from points2 in points1.  
   If there's no match, the point is discarded using Sequence[]. *)
match[point_]:= 
   With[{m=First@nf[point]}, 
       If[Norm[m-point]<threshold, {m,point}, Unevaluated@Sequence[]]
   ]

(* find matching point-pairs *)
matches=match/@points1;

(* build hash tables to retrieve the properties associated with points quickly *)
Clear[values1,values2]
Set[values1[{#1,#2}],#3]&@@@list1;
Set[values2[{#1,#2}],#3]&@@@list2;

(* get the property-pairs *)
{values1[#1],values2[#2]}&@@@matches
```

An altrenative is to use a custom `DistanceFunction` in nearest to avoid the use of `values1` & `values2`, and have a shorter program.  This may be slower or faster, I didn't test this with large data at all.

<sub>**Note:** How complicated the implementation needs to be really depends on your particular dataset.  Does each point from the first set have a match in the second one?  Are there any duplicates?  How close can points from the same dataset be?  Etc.  I tried to provide something which can be tweaked to be relatively robust, at the cost of having longer code.</sub>